# How to run code at a specific time in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, file-upload, web-applications

I have  ASP.NET MVC 5 application. one of the key functionalities of my application is upload pdf file and  through ocr read some values  and makes other stuff.

**Now i wanted implement functionality, through  which my app should at specific time check, specific folder for example(pdf_folder) and check if there is  pdf file or files and upload each and every pdf automatically and perform the rest of the logic of my application. After finishing uploading all files it should move all  to another folder(finished_folder).**

For example this is my controller which handles the uploade file when user mannualy upload pdf via my application.
I  just wanted to make this process autmatically at specific time.

```
 public ActionResult GetAlreadyScannedFileList(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string path = "";

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {


                UploadFileModel uploadFileModel = new UploadFileModel();

                uploadFileModel.FileName = path;
                uploadFileModel.UserId = 1;

                //Unique guid should be generated for each and every uplaoded file.
                Guid guid;
                Session["Guid"] = guid = _uploadFileService.AddUploadFile(uploadFileModel);

                //Save chnages.
                _unitOfWork.Commit();

                UploadFileModel uploadFile = _uploadFileService.GetUploadFileByGuid(guid);
                int uploadFileId = uploadFile.UploadFileId;

                _uploadFileService.ArchiveUploadFile(uploadFile.FileName);

                //send complete mail
                _uploadFileService.SendMailAfterComplete(uploadFileId);

                return RedirectToAction("SplittedItems", "UploadFile", new { id = uploadFileId });


                return RedirectToAction("GetAlreadyScannedFileList");

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many solutions to this problem. Here are 2 options I use:

1. To use the library Quartz.Net to create the scheduled tasks. [Documentation](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/quick-start.html)
2. Write a console application, and add it to Windows scheduler, for example. The application will call the desired method.
3. For dot net core applications : [Implement background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice)

These approaches solve the problem of falling asleep application

Answer (score 3):

You have to use background jobs for this task.
There are two ways

1. Using task scheduler (you will need to create an console app with 
   your logic e.g the task you want to do) and add it to task
   scheduler.
2. Using hangfire (https://www.hangfire.io/)